# Powershell: find/replace string using wildcard - syntax difficulty

Tags: shell, powershell

I have the following text in a file named ".connectionInfo":

```
device name = "WTG001" {
    address = "172.28.16.1";
    port = 80;
    timeout = 3;
    rfs = true;
    operatingSystem = "vxworks";
}
```

I have one file as the master (shown above) and wish to create multiple copies in multiple directories with this IP address incrementing by one. In directory "WTG001", I would have .connectionInfo with "172.28.16.1", in directory "WTG002", I would have .connectionInfo with "172.28.16.2", etc.

I have the following Powerscript file and would like to use a counter (IP_Counter) to increment the last digits of the IP address:

```
$folder="C:\work\Scripting";
$txtFile="C:\work\Scripting\TurbineConfig.txt";
$pattern="\d+.+";

get-content $txtFile | %
{
    $IP_Counter = 1

    if($_ -match $pattern)
    {
        Copy-Item -Path C:\work\Scripting\.connectionInfo -Destination "$folder\$_.vxworks";
        (Get-Content C:\work\Scripting\.connectionInfo) | 
            Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '172.28.16.*','172.28.16.$IP_Counter'}  | 
            Out-File "$folder\.connectionInfo";
        $IP_Counter++;
    ...
    }
}
```

I'm having problems with the proper syntax for the "-replace" attribute. I want to replace just the last 3 digits of the IP address with the value $IP_Counter.  I think using '172.28.16.*' wildcard ***finds*** the last number in the IP but I cannot figure out the precise syntax for the ***replace*** string. Please help me identify what '172.28.16.$IP_Counter' should look like.

I can use that same knowledge to replace the "WTG001" text also.

Comment: `-replace` uses a regex, in a regex a dot is any char. To match a literal dot you have to escape with a backslash. So `Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '172\.28\.16\.\d{1,3}',"172.28.16.$IP_Counter"}` Also vars in single quotes aren't expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `-replace` expression:

```
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '172\.28\.16\.\d+',"172.28.16.$IP_Counter"}
```

`\d+` represents digits only so the semicolon at the end of the line and the quotes won't be replaced. You also need to use double quotes `"` around the replacement string to interpolate `$IP_Counter`

I hope there is also some bounds checking for `$IP_Counter` - in your example it looks like it would loop forever.